# Свойство Filter и запись расширений видео файлов в него C#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, filter

У openFileDialog есть свойство Filter, как прописать туда расширения только видео файлов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перечислить расширения для видео-файлов, [согласно документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
openFileDialog.Filter = "Movie Files (*.mpg, *.avi)|*.mpg;*.avi";
```

Comment: @Макс: Если помогло, поставьте зелёную галочку слева от ответа.